# Error using subprocess to call blender

Tags: python, scripting

This different from [Calling Blender From Python Script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/calling-blender-from-python-script) in that it concentrates on a different part of the code which results in different error messages. It is also a more clearly stated problem.

I have a very simple python script that I copied from [How to Run blender from a python program?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58185/how-to-run-blender-from-a-python-program)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("blender", "proj001-master.blend ")
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testsubprocess.py", line 2, in 
>       subprocess.call("blender", "proj001-master.blend ")
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
>       return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 343, in **init**
>       raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
>   TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

I changed the code to:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("blender", "proj001-master.blend ")
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testsubprocess.py", line 2, in 
>       subprocess.Popen("blender", "proj001-master.blend ")
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 343, in **init**
>       raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
>   TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you needed to amend your question you should have used the 'edit' button below it, not asked it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Blender From Python Script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/calling-blender-from-python-script)

Comment: looks like the arguments have to be in a list format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824096/bufsize-must-be-an-integer-error-while-grepping-a-message

Comment: I tried:
    subprocess.call(["blender", "proj001-master.blend"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
subprocess.Popen(["blender", "proj001-master.blend"])
```